# sympy differential equality

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I'm trying to setup sympy to calculate derivatives. When I test it with simple equation, I'm finding the same answer (equality is true between sympy calculation and my own calculation). However when I try with more complicated ones, when it doesnt work (I checked answers with wolfram alpha too).

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import simplify, cos, sin, expand
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)

equation = (x**3*y-x*y**3)/(x**2+y**2)
equation2 = (x**4*y+4*x**2*y**3-y**5)/((x**2+y**2)**2)


pprint(equation)
print ""
pprint(equation2)


print diff(equation,x) == equation2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common "gotcha" in Sympy. For creating symbolic equalities, you should use `sympy.Eq` and *not* `=` or `==` (see the [tutorial](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs)). For your example,

```
Eq(equation.diff(x), equation2).simplify()
```

> `True`

Note, as above, that you may have to call `simplify()` in order to see wheather the `Eq` object corresponds to `True` or `False`